# VB.NET localization, detect untranslated text

Tags: vb.net, resources, localization, culture, fallback

I'm working on a project, where the localization is mostly done using resource files/cultures. If a translation does not exist for the language, the default language is used.

I recently received the task of reviewing some problems with the translation. Some text is in the default language, some not. Why it has not been translated is not always obvious, as there are cases when the resource files are not used, or have not been translated. I would love to be able to see what is the case without having to check the code.

What I would like to have is that everytime the fallback language is used instead of the requested language, that the text gets a "*" in front of it. this would enable me to know when simply a translation is missing in the resource file. So far I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zeta resource editor](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com/index.html) (open source) to easy match all resource strings and even complete them if necessary.

[image]

Comment: we are currently using "passolo", I think it can do this too. the issue I would like to solve, is being able to determine at runtime why some text-blocks have not been translated.
thanks for the suggestion though!